# Why does text disappear when the page is loaded? (Wordpress, CSS, HTML, JS issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I probably would be downvoded, cause I do not even know how to describe the problem.

I have a website (on Wordpress, template was bought and modified a bit thus I am not much into it yet and do not know all staff about it).

On the left side there is menu and on the right side some "test" text.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Navigation Start -->
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">   
        <div class="navigation">   
           <div class="mmm_fullwidth_container" style="width:1841px;left: -128.859375px;right:auto;"></div>                         
           <!-- navigation here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

So, everything is simple. Text on right side. However, if I open the website (http://moneyti.co/) the text on right side is seen, but then disappear. There is some *.js or something that creates this effect. The result of *.js (I am not able to say which JS does this, unfortunately) is `mmm_fullwidth_container` element inside the "navigation" part. This element has the following CSS:

```
element.style {
    width: 1841px;
    left: -128.859375px;
    right: auto;
}
```

As a result "text on right part" is somehow "under" this `mmm_fullwidth_container`.

Even if it is *.js that hides the element, I am not able to make it visible by changing CSS dynamically in browser. The element with text "test" is present in HTML markup, but I am not really able to understand why this text disappears. Why is the text not seen on the screen?

Comment: Can we see the .js file? Also, it's a long shot but it's worth a try - put a <p> tag over 'test'.

Comment: Unfourtunately I do not know which *.js file does this, but I have found out, that in right column a new element appears (some  *.js file creates it). And this element overlaps "test" text.  I have updated my question.

Comment: So it isn't simply the text that's the issue per-say but rather the element itself? If so, try putting a z-index of 9999 on the class you're having issues with.

Comment: z-index helped, I tried to put it on element with "test" text, but I have to put it on div with column styles.

Comment: Can you please quote the text that is dissapearing? I don't understand what element you are talking about. Another option would be to `view-source` and tell the line number of that element?

Comment: Might want to consider rounding your `-128.859375px` value. Any decimals will not be shown, as you cannot color half a pixels, for instance.